# How to predict the Temperature value for tomorrow.

Tags: probability

I have the temperature value for every hour for the past 7 days each having 24 slots each.How can i predict the Temperature for each slots tomorrow more precisely with this data.I would like to have predicted data for each 24 slots for tomorrow.I trust this must use probability or some thing.

And i trust weight age must be given more to the previous day in relation to other days values.

How can i more precisely predict this values.

Thank you

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try with [FFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform). What is your math background?

The mathematical explanation is that you would like to interpolate your data with a superposition of periodic functions (waves) like $\sin$ and $\cos$. A 24h period is expected in your data, and can be exploited by Fourier analysis. Once you have found a Fourier series for your data, you can evaluate the resulting function with time in the future. Google keywords: fft interpolation.

The implementation is much dependent on what is your programming environment. If you need help with this I think you should ask on stackoverflow.  My preference would be to use numpy/python.

Comment: Hey thank you for your reply.:) i'm bit new to transforms and all.But i will try that.Can you explain that method.

Comment: How can i use FFT to predict the values?.Can you explain the Practical uses in relation with this problem.

Comment: I have added some more explanation.